# What CSS is causing this submenu to be lower than it should be?

Tags: html, css

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tGUZu/)

If you hover over products, a dropdown menu should appear (displaying appliance and other), then when you hover over appliance, another submenu should appear (displaying black and white), however this second submenu appears to be 2-3 pixels lower than the parent menu. What CSS is causing it to be lower?

Here's the CSS:

```css
*{
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
}

#navbar{
    list-style: none; 
    float: right; 
    padding-top: 54px; 
    position: relative; 
}

#navbar li{
    float:left; 
    width: 130px;
    text-align: center;  
}

#navbar li a{
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    color: #524F4F; 
    font-weight: 600; 
}

#navbar li a:hover{
    color: #f3a82e; 
}




#navbar ul{
    list-style: none; 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%;    
}

.firstnavmenu{
    padding-top: 10px; 
}

#navbar ul li{
    float: none; 
    position: relative; 
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    height: 30px; 
    border-top: 3px solid white; 
}

#navbar ul li a{
    padding-top: 6px; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;  
    display: block; 
}

#navbar li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
}

#navbar li li:hover{
    background-color: #edeaea;
}

#navbar ul ul{
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100%;
    top:0;
    display:  none; 
}

#navbar ul ul:hover > ul {
    display: block; 
}
```

and heres the html:

```html
<ul id="navbar">
    <li>
        <a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
        <ul class="firstnavmenu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">APPLIANCE</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">BLACK </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">WHITE</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">OTHER</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">TECHNOLOGY</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">PARTNERS</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">COMPANY</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 3 px solid white border.

Remove it from the 2nd `ul li:first-child`

```css
#navbar ul ul li:first-child {
    border-top:none;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the border and have them maintain the same height? I need that white top-border there.

Comment: If you want to keep that border (but really, why would you need it on the first element?) but fine... say you do.. then just give the 2nd ul a negative top margin like `#navbar ul ul {margin-top: -3px;}`

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css

```
ul.firstnavmenu li ul{
    margin-top:-3px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abdulmalik/UuunS/)